# How to extract texts from text node isolating the <br> tags within table?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I'm having an issue printing out in the same row, table data. Of course, I could just identify with `css_selector("td")`, but that prints out:
Name
Address
City/State
Phone in the same column
whereas I'm trying to create: 
Name, Address, City/State, Phone to the same row

HTML: (see attached photo)

This seems like such a stupid problem to be hung up on... but I've been stuck for quite some time, and haven't been able to isolate `<br>` tags.

Code:

```
for x in link:
driver.get(x)
try:
    i = 0
    while 0 < 20:
        name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr['"+str(i)+"']/td/strong")
        if name[i].is_displayed():
            print(name[i].text)

            i = i + 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
except(NoSuchElementException,JavascriptException, IndexError):
    continue
```

I've identified it this way to try to simply return text of proceding siblings... again to no avail. `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")`
Also returns the entire table data... but with it's breaks

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: It's likely not directly related to the issue, but what's going on with the `while 0 < 20:` and `i = i + 1;
        else:
            i = i + 1;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<br>` add new line `\n` to the text of the `<td>`, you split by it or remove it

```
tds = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")
for td in tds:
     text = td.text.split('\n')
     print(text) # list: ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']

     text = td.text.replace('\n', ' ')
     print(text) # str: 'textr text2 text3 text4'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to identify the parent `<td>` element with [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) `css_selector("td")` to print **Name**, **Address**, **City/State** and **Phone** you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Name*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td>strong"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- *Address*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td")))).strip())
  ```
- *City/State*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td")))).strip())
  ```
- *Phone*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td")))).strip())
  ```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup can also be used in this scenario.

```
>>>from bs4 import beautifulsoup
>>>import requests
>>>contents=requests.get(url).text

>>>soup=beautifulsoup('lxml',contents)

>>>>Text=soup.find('body').text
```

and check for condition if 'br' tag is there then skip

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in link:
driver.get(x)
try:

    names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")
    i = 0
    while i <= len(names):
        address = names[i].text.splitlines()
        r = len(address)

        if r == 4:
            print(x, " | ",address[0], " | ", address[1], " | ", address[2], " | ", address[3])


        elif r == 3:

            print(x, " | ",address[0], " | ", address[1], " | ", address[2])

        else:
            pass
        i=i+1


except(NoSuchElementException, IndexError):
    continue
```

This did the job.